# How do I filter / restrict entries field in CP with a category

Tags: categories, control-panel, relations, entries-field

Is there a way to restrict the entry field type to specific categories? For example when adding a new field with type "Entries" to select the categories from where entries will be available.

I found this https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-dynamicfields which is cool, but offers dropdowns and checkboxes that only work with a single entry. http://screencast.com/t/15nIkpHTQ1